# Easy z-index challenge: making a sibling disappear behind another sibling?

Tags: html, css

This is what I want it to look like:

[image]

everything that is inside the red div, must go behind the green div.
The html:

```
<div style="height: 100px">some text blablablablablablabla
    <br/>some text blablablablablablabla
    <br/>some text
    <br/>some text
    <br/>some text
    <br/>some text
    <br/>some text
    <br/>
</div>
<nav class="navigation">
    <div class="navfake"></div>
    <div class="singleelement">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="title">Some Title1</div>
            <div class="titlepicture">some picture</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="singleelement">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="title">Some Title2</div>
            <div class="titlepicture">some picture</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
```

The CSS so far and sadly not working:

```
nav {
    width: 100%;
    height: 60px;
    position: relative;
}
.navfake {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: green;
    z-index: 10;
}
.singleelement {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100px;
    height: 60px;
    text-align: center;
    z-index: 0;
}
.container {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
     -webkit-transition: all .8s ease;
        -moz-transition: all .8s ease;
        -ms-transition: all .8s ease;
        -o-transition: all .8s ease;
        transition: all .8s ease;
    height: 200px;
}
.titlepicture {
    width: 100%;
    height: 200px;
    background-color: red;

}


.singleelement:hover .container {
    top: -80px;

}
```

[enter link description here](http://jsfiddle.net/hL5gW/3/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Credits also for: @Toskan, thank you

[DEMO WORKING](http://jsfiddle.net/8hVWz/1/)

Here's the new css

```
 nav {
    width: 100%;
    height: 60px;
    position: relative;
}
.navfake {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: green;
    z-index: 10;
    position:relative;
}
.singleelement {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100px;
    height: 60px;
    text-align: center;
}
.container {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
     -webkit-transition: all .8s ease;
        -moz-transition: all .8s ease;
        -ms-transition: all .8s ease;
        -o-transition: all .8s ease;
        transition: all .8s ease;
    height: 200px;
}
.titlepicture {
    position:absolute;         /*THIS ADDED*/
    width: 100%;
    height: 200px;
    background-color: red;
    z-index:1;            /*THIS ADDED*/
}


.singleelement:hover .container {
    top: -80px;

}

.title{                         /*THIS ADDED*/
    z-index:555; 
    position:relative;

}
```

HTML:

```
<br><br>
<div style="height: 100px">some text blablablablablablabla
    <br/>some text blablablablablablabla
    <br/>some text
    <br/>some text
    <br/>some text
    <br/>some text
    <br/>some text
    <br/>
</div>
<nav class="navigation">
    <div class="navfake"></div>
    <div class="singleelement">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="title">Some Title1</div>
            <div class="titlepicture">some picture</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="singleelement">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="title">Some Title2</div>
            <div class="titlepicture">some picture</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: the problem is that now the red is behind everything, including the text above it. It should be behind green, but in front of the stuff that goes so beautifully "some text blablablablablablabla 
some text blablablablablablabla 
some text "

Comment: I fixed it, http://jsfiddle.net/8hVWz/1/
update your answer and I might accept it. You had some flaws in the css you provided. E.g. .title does not do anything as long as it is not position absolute, relative, or fixed

Comment: just wanna put this here for reference, a little update i did together with ideas from others.
http://jsfiddle.net/8hVWz/3/

Answer (score 1):

http://jsfiddle.net/hL5gW/4/

Adding position absolute and doing some positioning this is incredibly simple.

I added these styles to the second element. You'll just have to add it to a seperate class for the second element, or just add it to `singleelement` if you want this to apply to both.

```
 <div class="singleelement" style="z-index:-100;position:absolute;margin-top:-60px;">
```

Comment: It's all magic to me... I was just searching around a bit and don't have a clear answer yet. But I've done this before, and it works. :)

Comment: @Toskan and it also seems that `position:relative;` works as well. I'm going to assume that it just needed a position. The way I understand it the only limitation you have is if you have another element with a higher z-index than the parent (in this case `nav`) you won't be able to make children of `nav` appear higher than that other element. If that makes sense.

Comment: i couldn't get it to work with position relative. Now I see why not, you actually have the exact same problem. Your solution doesn't work either if the z-index is higher than 0. -100 just puts it behind everything, including normal content in the body. So this won't solve my problem sadly. It gotta be in front of the body content, and behind the green bar.

Comment: Can't you just set your body z-index to a number lower than it?

Comment: And... http://jsfiddle.net/hL5gW/5/... There doesn't seem to be any problem... It's still in front of the body here.

Comment: -100 is relative only to the `nav` container which is on-top of the body so there is no problem. (I think...) If it's not working on your specific site there are probably other things in play. http://jsfiddle.net/hL5gW/7/ Here is another example where I placed a random content div with `z-index:-101;` and it works.

Comment: you do realize, that the yellow element you placed there, is behind everything else? and that was exactly what I was stating, that is incorrect

Comment: @Toskan Well, you said "-100 just puts it behind everything, including normal content in the body" which I have shown is not true. Currently, all of my JSFIDDLEs show the element in question "in front of the body content, and behind the green bar." I fail to see the issue.

Comment: I think we have a misunderstanding here. I don't seem to understand.
Maybe we browser issue? what browser are you using? You have actually shown, that the quoted sentence is true. It is behind everything, I can read everything and see ALL elements that were put into this fiddle, not only the green bar

Comment: It doesn't seem like there is any browser breaking code in the css. I had some weird problems with a page I was working on a little while ago showing unexplainable differences between Firefox and Chrome  before I set the doctype. I'm using FireFox now. 

I suppose we should just leave it be though ;). Glad you got it working.